# Why does H2 alias duplicate inserted rows?

Tags: java, h2

I have created the following H2 alias:

```
CREATE ALIAS INSERT_CHANGE_RECORD AS  '
java.sql.ResultSet insertChangeRecord(final java.sql.Connection conn) throws java.sql.SQLException
{
  String sql = "insert into `change_records` (`made_when`, `made_by`) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(9), ''admin'');";
  java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
  ps.executeUpdate();
  java.sql.ResultSet results = ps.getGeneratedKeys() ;
  return results;
}
';
```

Weirdly enough, when I call the alias (once) using `call INSERT_CHANGE_RECORD();` 3 identical records are created in the table, instead of one.

When I use the following definition of the alias instead (the difference is that I actually retrieve the generated ID from the resultset), only 1 row is inserted.

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS INSERT_CHANGE_RECORD AS  '
Long insertChangeRecord(final java.sql.Connection conn) throws java.sql.SQLException
{
  String sql = "insert into `change_records` (`made_when`, `made_by`) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(9), ''admin'');";
  java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
  ps.executeUpdate();
  java.sql.ResultSet results = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
  results.next();
  return results.getLong(1);
}
';
```

Is this a bug in H2, or is there any reasonable explanation for this behavior? I'm using H2 *2.1.210*.

Here is the DDL of the table that I insert into.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `change_records` (
    `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT CONSTRAINT `change_records_id_pk` PRIMARY KEY,
    `made_when` TIMESTAMP (9) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    `made_by` VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function aliases returning a `ResultSet` are called multiple times. You need to check URL of passed connection. If it is equal to `jdbc:columnlist:connection`, you need to return an empty `ResultSet` with properly configured columns, you can use `org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet` or some other implementation. These invocations are performed during compilation or recompilation of the query before its actual execution.

```java
String url = conn.getMetaData().getURL();
if (url.equals("jdbc:columnlist:connection")) {
    SimpleResultSet rs = new SimpleResultSet();
    // With some connection options "id" should be used instead
    rs.addColumn("ID", Types.BIGINT, 19, 0);
    return rs;
}
// main code
```

This result set must have columns with exactly the same names and data types as your function normally returns. Be careful with column names, `` `id` `` usually means `"ID"`, but if `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` or `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` were specified in JDBC URL used by your application, it means `"id"`. Your function shouldn't modify any data during this execution, it is only asked about its metadata.

If URL is different, it is a real function call during execution of a query or other command and you need to execute your code.

See also an example:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/45b609dec0e45125e6a93f85c9018d34551332a1/h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/Function.java#L140